# Any way to force divs to group up?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a series of floating divs without set height arranged so that three fit across the screen. With set height they stay like a tabular layout but if the text in one is longer than the text in another the boxes split up in an odd way.

Is there any way to force the boxes to group up so that the margin between the sides of any two subsequent divs will be enforced or do I just have to set a specific height?

Comment: Mozilla has a great article addressing browser issues, etc. on doing this type of thing: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

It might be of use to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something similar to what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/9xpja/

It's using `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`.

If what you mean is to have them all fit in like blocks then you'll need to do something like the other solutions posted by others by creating "columns".

Comment: That is what i was looking for but adding those two lines to the div elements did not move them. Really thought vert-al would do it too.

Comment: @Magic Lasso: You would have to remove `float: left` for `display: inline-block` to work.

Comment: What @thirtydot said, also I believe some versions of IE (maybe just 6) will not accept `inline-block` on block elements so you need to make them spans instead of divs.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put each column in a seperate div, that way you'll get rid of the gaps. But the divs wont be align to each other anymore.

Comment: Yea was hoping to avoid that because the whole thing is generated in PHP and I didnt want to have to add a counter. But this is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could always add the three column divs inside a parent row div. Then just set the vertical alignment of the parent div.  That will cause them to conform and "Group Up".